# Difference between two merges of same GIT branch

Tags: git, github, merge, git-diff

Let's say I have a remote repo `XYZ` and the branches `TEST` and `TEST1`.

I pulled the remote `XYZ` to my local `XYZ` repo and switched to branch `TEST1`.

I made couple of commits and pushed to the remote. Then I merged from `TEST1` to `TEST` (merge A).

I made few more commits to `TEST1` and pushed them to the remote. Then I merged all these commits to `TEST` (merge B).

#### Question:

How do I find the differences and list out all the files that were changed or added between these two merges (merge A and merge B), in the branch `TEST`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git diff --name-only ${MERGE_SHA_A}..${MERGE_SHA_B}
```

should show the diff files, without the --name-only you will see the actual diff if this is what you mean

```
git log
```

should list commits if you need the ids

Comment: Thanks. I need to use these  `git log --merges -n 2 --format="%H"` and `git diff --name-only ${MERGE_SHA_A} ${MERGE_SHA_B}`

Answer (score 0):

Find the commit of the first merge commit and the one before the second merge commit and diff them with `git diff <id1> <id2>`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, this is roughly what your commit graph should look like in a GUI:

```
x1 ------ A ------- B     <-- TEST
 \       /         /
  y1 - y2 - y3 - y4       <-- TEST1
```

My preferred answer, rather than using the command-line, is to use a GUI to select the commits and send them to a visual diff tool.

In [Git Extensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions), as an example,

- Check out `TEST` by right-clicking the B commit on the top line, and selecting **[Checkout Branch > TEST]**
- Then right-click on the A commit, and select **[Compare > Compare with current branch]**
- This will pull up the diff in whatever diff tool you setup (like KDiff3, which comes with the install package currently). No need to copy or paste any hashes, etc. (though they are available easily enough by clicking on any commit and looking at the "Commit" tab on the bottom half of the screen).

KDiff3 visually shows you each modified, added, or deleted file on the left, and you can click on any of them to see the exact changes on the right.

The command-line works fine - especially for small changes when you already know the hashes, or your repo is uncomplicated and you are able to find them quickly, but I find, on average, running a GUI in the background and swapping to it for most tasks like this is the best workflow for me.